# assimp demo loading 3d model

Tags: opengl, assimp

I'm having my first try with assimp loading a 3D model. The example is given here from lighthouse3d [link](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/cg-topics/code-samples/importing-3d-models-with-assimp/)

It compiles without errors. However, I get a similar error to the error Jeffrey had discussed with the comments below the post.

```
Ready for OpenGL 3.3
Import of scene bench.obj succeeded.WARNING: 0:? : ” : Version number deprecate
d in OGL 3.0 forward compatible context driver

No errors.

WARNING: 0:? : ” : Version number deprecated in OGL 3.0 forward compatible cont
ext driver
ERROR: 0:35: ‘texture2D’ : function is removed in Forward Compatibile context
ERROR: 0:35: ‘texture2D’ : no matching overloaded function found (using implicit
conversion)
ERROR: 0:35: ‘assign’ : cannot convert from ‘const float’ to ’4-component vecto
r of float’

Vendor: Intel
Renderer: Intel(R) HD Graphics 2500
Version: 3.3.0 – Build 9.17.10.2875
GLSL: 3.30 – Build 9.17.10.2875
```

and probably the example was fixed so this error seems not to reappear. But it shows another one, my case:

```
Ready for OpenGL 3.3
Import of scene bench.obj succeeded.WARNING: 0:? : ” : Version number deprecate
d in OGL 3.0 forward compatible context driver

No errors.

WARNING: 0:? : ” : Version number deprecated in OGL 3.0 forward compatible cont
ext driver
ERROR: 0:16: ‘output’ : reserved keyword
ERROR: 0:16: ‘output’ : syntax error syntax error
    
Vendor: Intel
Renderer: Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000
Version: 3.3.0 – Build 9.17.10.2843
GLSL: 3.30 – Build 9.17.10.2843
```

if possible, I'm trying not to get deeper in computer graphics, just simply load the model

Any suggestion?

Edit01:
I think this would be the shader code: [link](http://pastebin.com/HkhRXj0x)

Edit02:
I've looked it up in a separate text file dirlightdiffambpix.frag and there is the var output in it [link](http://pastebin.com/QcKEwGFu)

And I think I've fixed it already since the error is simply "output" is a reserved keyword and the corresponding var's name should be changed to ... output1 for example

Comment: Can you post your shader code? That is what those errors are referencing. Basically your shader is written against a language version that is different from your context.

Comment: PS: I've tried with the author but his google group seems not to work anymore

Comment: That pastebin code is not shader code, that is C. I want the GLSL you are using. Honestly you are not going to get anywhere if you don't take the time to understand how the code you are using works.

Comment: @Heuvel: I'll update it soon. Thank you!

Comment: the demo has run without error already. thanks!

Comment: I think it's better to give an answer to this question so that it can be marked as accomplished. It's solved anyway!

Comment: Then add an answer with clear steps as to how you fixed your problem and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked it up in a separate text file dirlightdiffambpix.frag and there is the var output in it [link](http://pastebin.com/QcKEwGFu)

I've fixed it already since the error is simply "output" is a reserved keyword and the corresponding var's name should be changed to ... output1 for example and it simply works by then