# loading binary STL model with assimp

Tags: opengl, model, assimp

I've started to get familiar with Assimp. My tasks with this library is quite simple, just to load a 3D model, visualize it and sparse neccessary information from it e.g. facets, facet normals... probably some manipulatinos with camera

I've successfully loaded several models at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19841602/assimp-demo-loading-3d-model?noredirect=1#comment29789467_19841602)

the example given here can load obj and ascii stl models. However, the same task cannot be done with STL binary model which generates an error like: "ASCII file is empty or invalid; no data loaded - could not load model"

two other references confirm me that my error is not the first one:

[link1](http://sourceforge.net/p/assimp/discussion/817654/thread/c38dd95d)

[link2](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4740)

the 2nd link recommends to use ivcon as a solution. however the post was quite 3 years ago

How about the current solution? can I fix it directly with some import command settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my bad! I was so closed to the answer which is already there in link2 but I didn't even try it.

So, just now, I simply changed the STL file's header "solid" to any other group of characters such as "abcde" and the import works normally